# How to debug 0 mb unnamed uploads?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, jinja2, blobstore

Looking from the datastore console admin blobstore viewer it appears many files are 0 sizes:

[image]

Could you comment or say why this has happened? I think the file upload code I have is pretty clean so where is the bug?

```
for upload in self.get_uploads():
    try:
        img = Image(reference=ad)
        img.primary_image = upload.key()
        img.put()
        ad.put()
    except:
        pass
```

I suspect I can recreate this bug by [uploading a file](http://www.koolbusiness.com/ai) to the blobstore and then both the file and a zero upload will be created. How else do you think I should troubleshoot this bug?

Thank you

**Update**

I can reproduce the bug uploading just one file and leave the other fields blank then the blank fields will create the blank datastore files:

```
<tr><td>
<div class="labelform">
    <label>{% trans %}Post a photo{% endtrans %}</label>
  </div></td><td>
  <div class="adinput">
    <input type="file" name="file" size="35" id="file" />{% trans %}Optional{% endtrans %}{{resize}}
  </div>
  </td></tr><tr><td>
  <div class="labelform">
    <label>{% trans %}Post a photo{% endtrans %}</label>
  </div></td><td>
  <div class="adinput">
    <input type="file" name="file2" size="35" id="file2" /> {% trans %}Optional{% endtrans %}
  </div></td></tr><tr><td>
<div class="labelform">
    <label>{% trans %}Post a photo{% endtrans %}</label>
  </div></td><td>
  <div class="adinput">
    <input type="file" name="file3" size="35" id="file3" /> {% trans %}Optional{% endtrans %}
  </div>
  </td></tr><tr><td>
  <div class="labelform">
    <label>{% trans %}Post a photo{% endtrans %}</label>
  </div></td><td>
    <input type="file" name="file4" size="35" id="file4" /> {% trans %}Optional{% endtrans %}
  </td></tr><tr><td>
<div class="labelform">
    <label>{% trans %}Post a photo{% endtrans %}</label></div></td><td><div class="adinput"><input type="file" name="file5" size="35" id="file5" /> {% trans %}Optional{% endtrans %}</div></td></tr><tr><td></td><td><div class="labelform"></div><div class="adinput">

<input type="submit" name="validate" value='{% trans %}Go{% endtrans %}' /></div></td></tr>
```

Comment: Can you try out your suspicion and see if it's the case? What does your HTML form look like? What happens if you log self.get_uploads?

Comment: Thank you for asking. It is the case that uploading one file with the rest of the form fields left blank generates the blank unnamed files in the blobstore. I update the question with my HTML form also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're specifying multiple file fields, so the datastore is attempting to process multiple files. This might be considered a bug in the blobstore (in which case you could [file one](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/entry)), but if your browser is submitting the empty fields, it's unclear to me what the proper response is.

You could work around this by deleting the empty files, or (better) by using Javascript to automatically add and subtract file input fields as required for the actual number of files the user wants to upload.

Comment: Thank you @Nick Johnson for the answer

Answer (score 1):

Using Google's experimental code (need to tweak it for multiple files).

```
my_upload = self.request.POST['file']
my_data = my_upload.file.read()

if len(my_data) > 0:
    # Create the file
    file_name = files.blobstore.create(mime_type='application/octet')

    # Open the file and write to it
    with files.open(file_name, 'b') as f:
      f.write(my_data)

    # Finalize the file. Do this before attempting to read it.
    files.finalize(file_name)

    # Get the file's blob key
    blob_key = files.blobstore.get_blob_key(file_name)
    self.response.out.write(blob_key)
```

Comment: yes that's good but it makes more send to use `blostoreuploadhandler`that will generate the fileformat and other stuff behing the scenes. Do you agree that I should use `blobstoreuploadhandler` if I do a for file upload instead of the raw files api where I must manually specify the filename and MIME type so it's not as forward-compatible as blobstoreuploadhandler?

Comment: This [site](http://netgamix.wordpress.com/2011/01/25/a-simple-blobstore-file-uploader/) answers your question in dealing with multiple files upload using `blobstoreuploadhandler`. My style is more suited to the low-level 'file-like API' and yes, it is experimental and may not be forward-compatible.